# How do I setup a jQuery DatePicker with a formatted date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when a date is picked it shows up month/day/ format, but I want it to be day/month/year

I tried this but it does not work:
    $.datepicker.formatDate( "dd-mm-yy");

Also Would it be possible to have a dropdown of years or an extra over arrow for years as well as months?

I haved look through the documentation and api but am lost as to where to put the code? in the soucre or in the html?

My example is located [here](http://www.taffatech.com/Demo.html)  Then click the create new user button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add this to the settings when initializing a datepicker :

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
                        changeYear: true,       //enabled drop down for year
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"  //changes the format
                             });
```

Comment: Thank you, also the dropdown is limited to a range of years, can I alter this?

Comment: Edit: I can now pick back to 100 years. Thanks